# Should we allow questions about a unique item's price?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Question: [How do I determine the value of a knife?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/270540/i-need-help-for-the-pricing-for-this-knife)

Should we allow questions like this? They only help the asker, the answer only applies to the particular pictured item and there can be many answers to such a question as the answers can not be exact or subjective (the real price of something is what a buyer will pay for it).

In this particular case, That item costs [$73](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/%E2%98%85%20Shadow%20Daggers%20%7C%20Case%20Hardened%20(Field-Tested)), the asker wants us to get a price for it considering its color, float and pattern. It is subjective.

Comment: I'd be inclined to say it should not be allowed. These kind of questions are about a specific piece that's often unique, and contributes no value to anyone but the person asking the question. Even then, they could be given incorrect information which causes monetary harm. I'd stay clear of these kind of questions, and hopefully this won't be the kind of place people go to for appraisals.

Comment: @Thebluefish if you can extend that a bit, you can post that as an answer